# Parse an input file into two separate files in java

Tags: java

I have a input file as like below (for example):

```
10 12
1
2
...
9
10
1
2
...
11
12
```

The first tells that the next 10 lines are for `part1`

Then following next 12 lines are for `part2`.

I would like to create two separate files `part1.txt` and `part2.txt` parsing the original `input.txt` file.

How can do that? Any suggestions kindly? I am using java Scanner.

Solution (partial): that worked for me based on the suggestions below

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(filename);        
    try {
        String[] first_line = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+", 3); // reading the first line of the input file

        int EdgeCount = Integer.parseInt(first_line[0]);    
        int VertexCount = Integer.parseInt(first_line[1]);  
        String hasWeight = first_line[2];

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            if(EdgeCount != 0) { // check whether any more edges are left to read from input file
                Scanner edge_scanner = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());

....
```

Comment: What did you try, and why is it not working ? If you didn't try anywthing, do you want us to write the whole program for you. Indeed, this is such a simple task, that it looks like a homework...

Comment: If you wanted just suggestions, it's simply parsing the first line for the number of lines to be captured and using that data to know how many lines to scan for the files. It's up to you to write the code.

Comment: It was not any homework and I was also not looking for any concrete implementations. I was only seeking for potential guidelines to approach. I already tried in my way which seems to me at the first place was not efficient and thats why asked here. Sorry that I didn't post my initial codes as those are looks quite hazy at the first look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this sounds like homework, I will not go into too much code detail, but you could read the first line, and then use the [`.split("\\s+")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method from the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class.

Once you do this, you will end up with an array with `10` in the first location and `12` in the second.

While you iterate over the next lines, simply keep a counter and check if the value of the counter is less than or equal to 10. If this holds, then you know that you need to output one file. If the condition no longer holds and the counter is now greater than `10` but less than or equal to `10 + 12`, then you know that you should print in the second file.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I used .split function along with procedure shown in below with Scanner to parse the input. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Read file line by line, write first 10 line to part1.txt then write after 12 line to part2.txt.

For this use such a this pattern:

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("your input file path") );

```
    String line = null;

    int lineCounter = 1;

    while( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
    if( (lineCounter % 23 ) < 11 )
    {
       //Write part1.txt
    }
    else if( (lineCounter %23) > 10 )
    {
        //write part2.txt
    }
    lineCounter++;
    }

    br.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
br  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fileName.txt"));
int first = scanner.nextInt(); //10
int second = scanner.nextInt();//12
int x = 0;
int j = 0;
while ((sCurrentLine  = br.readLine()) != null) 
   {
     if (x <= first)
     {
        x++;
        //write in 1st file
     }
     else if (j <= second)
     {
        j++;
        //write in 2nd file
     }
}
br.close();
```